# Can't verify mock method call from RxJava Subscriber

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to unit test presenter in my Android app. Method I'm trying to test looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean loadNextPage() {
    if (!mIsLoading) {
        mIsLoading = true;
        if (mViewReference.get() != null) {
            mViewReference.get().showProgress();
        }
        mService.search(mSearchQuery, ++mCurrentPage)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(itemsPage -> {
                            mIsLoading = false;
                            mTotalPages = itemsPage.getPagination().getTotalPages();
                            if (mViewReference.get() != null) {
                                mViewReference.get().showMovies(itemsPage.getItems());
                            }
                        },
                        error -> {
                            mIsLoading = false;
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, error.toString());
                        });
    }
    return mTotalPages == 0 || mCurrentPage < mTotalPages;
}
```

`mService` is Retrofit interface and `mService.search()` method returns RxJava's `Observable<SearchResults>`. My unit test code looks like this:

```
package mobi.zona.presenters;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.api.Service;
import com.example.model.Movie;
import com.example.model.SearchResults;
import com.example.views.MoviesListView;
import rx.Observable;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SearchPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    Service mService;
    @Mock
    MoviesListView mMoviesListView;

    @Test
    public void testLoadNextPage() throws Exception {
        String searchQuery = "the hunger games";
        SearchResults searchResults = new SearchResults();
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
        searchResults.setItems(movies);

        when(mService.search(searchQuery, 1)).thenReturn(Observable.just(new SearchResults()));

        MoviesListPresenter presenter = new SearchPresenter(mZonaService, mMoviesListView, searchQuery);
        presenter.loadNextPage();

        verify(mService, times(1)).search(searchQuery, 1);
        verify(mMoviesListView, times(1)).showProgress();
        verify(mMoviesListView, times(1)).showMovies(movies);
    }
}
```

The problem is the third `verify(mMoviesListView, times(1)).showMovies(movies);` line - it allways fails. Whem I'm trying to debug this test I see that control flow never goes into `.subscribe(itemPage - {...`. I think that it's something related to the fact that I'm subscribing on `Schedulers.io()` thread, but have no idea on how to fix this. Any ideas?
**EDIT 1:**
Changed the presenter to take `Scheduler`'s as constructor parameters. Changed test to look like this:

```
@Test
public void testLoadNextPage() throws Exception {
    String searchQuery = "the hunger games";
    SearchResults searchResults = new SearchResults();
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    searchResults.setItems(movies);

    when(mZonaService.search(searchQuery, 1)).thenReturn(Observable.just(new SearchResults()));

    MoviesListPresenter presenter = new SearchPresenter(mZonaService, mMoviesListView, searchQuery,
            Schedulers.test(), Schedulers.test());
    presenter.loadNextPage();

    verify(mZonaService, times(1)).search(searchQuery, 1);
    verify(mMoviesListView, times(1)).showProgress();
    verify(mMoviesListView, times(1)).showMovies(movies);
}
```

Still getting this test failure message:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mMoviesListView.showMovies([]);
-> at com.example.presenters.SearchPresenterTest.testLoadNextPage(SearchPresenterTest.java:46)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
mMoviesListView.showProgress();
-> at com.example.presenters.SearchPresenter.loadNextPage(SearchPresenter.java:41)
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but shouldn't test be like `.showMovies(eq(movies));` instead?

Answer (score 2):

In my apps interactors/use-cases/model (`mService` in your case) is responsible for specifying `Scheduler` for the operation (since it knows better what kind of operation it does).

So, move your `subscribeOn` to `mService`. After that your mock will work fine.

Going deeper, if now you'll want to test `mService` I would recommend you to make it "dependent" on `Scheduler`. In other words - add `Sheduler` as a constructor parameter.

```
public class MyService {

    private final Scheduler taskScheduler;

    public MyService(Scheduler taskScheduler) {
        this.taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
    }

    // ...

    public Observable<Something> query() {
        return someObservable.subscribeOn(taskScheduler);
    }
}
```

Then, in tests you can use `Schedulers.immediate()` and for actual app `Schedulers.io()` (or whatever you like, really).

Comment: `mService` is actually Retrofit interface - it's where I place methods definitions like `@GET(/blah/blah) Observable<SearchResult> search();` etc. So I can't move subscription into it.

Comment: @FyodorSherstobitov ah, I see. I always do an additional layer between the model and presenter (interactor). If that's not an option for you, then you can instead make `Presenter` depend on particular `Scheduler` (as in my example with `MyService`, but apply that to `Presenter`)

Comment: Updated presenter as you suggested. Still getting test failure. Updated main post with new code.

Comment: @FyodorSherstobitov `Schedulers.test()` is not what you need, try `Schedulers.immediate()`

Comment: changed to `Schedulers.immediate()` - result is the same. I'll try to isolate calls to Retrofit in interactor.